# UICollectionView "crashes" after update in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `NSManagedObject` *Photo* which has the properties:

```
promoted NSNumber(BOOL)
date NSDate
id NSNumber(Int32)
```

Then there is an `UICollectionView` which should display all Photos and has an `NSFetchedResultsController` and is the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate'. The FRC has the has the properties mentioned above as sortdescriptors (same order as above) and the promoted as sectionKey.

So the CollectionView should look as follwing:
The first section only shows the promoted photo in full width.
All other photos should be displayed in a grid in the second section.

This all works fine.

Now from time to time the promoted photo should change.

What I basically do is:

- Creating a background `NSMangagedObjectContext`
- fetching all photos
- wandering through all photos

  - if the new promoted photo is found, it will be marked as promoted
  - any other will marked as not promoted
- when done, saving the background context.

The background context is now merged with the maincontext

This all works, but when the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate'-methods kick in I get the following error:

```
2016-11-18 13:09:30.329[34954:1275641] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.5.2/UICollectionView.m:5420
2016-11-18 13:09:30.331633 [34954:1275641] [error] error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to insert item 1 into section 0, but there are only 1 items in section 0 after the update with userInfo (null)
```

But as I save after all changes happened I don't get it why it seems to struggle with the ammount of items in the first section.

My `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`-Methods look like this:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    _objectChanges = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    _sectionChanges = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert || type == NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete) {
        NSMutableIndexSet *changeSet = _sectionChanges[@(type)];
        if (changeSet != nil) {
            [changeSet addIndex:sectionIndex];
        } else {
            _sectionChanges[@(type)] = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:sectionIndex];
        }
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
        NSMutableArray *changeSet = _objectChanges[@(type)];
        if (changeSet == nil) {
            changeSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            _objectChanges[@(type)] = changeSet;
        }

        switch(type) {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [changeSet addObject:newIndexPath];
                break;
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [changeSet addObject:indexPath];
                break;
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                [changeSet addObject:indexPath];
                break;
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                [changeSet addObject:@[indexPath, newIndexPath]];
                break;
        }
}



- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{

        NSMutableArray *moves = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeMove)];
        if ([moves count] > 0) {
            NSMutableArray *updatedMoves = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[moves count]];

            NSMutableIndexSet *insertSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
            NSMutableIndexSet *deleteSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
            for (NSArray *move in moves) {
                NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath = move[0];
                NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = move[1];

                if ([deleteSections containsIndex:[oldIndexPath section]]) {
                    if (![insertSections containsIndex:[newIndexPath section]]) {
                        NSMutableArray *changeSet = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
                        if (changeSet == nil) {
                            changeSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:newIndexPath, nil];
                            _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)] = changeSet;
                        } else {
                            [changeSet addObject:newIndexPath];
                        }
                    }
                } else if ([insertSections containsIndex:[newIndexPath section]]) {
                    NSMutableArray *changeSet = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
                    if (changeSet == nil) {
                        changeSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:oldIndexPath, nil];
                        _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)] = changeSet;
                    } else {
                        [changeSet addObject:oldIndexPath];
                    }
                } else {
                    [updatedMoves addObject:move];
                }
            }

            if ([updatedMoves count] > 0) {
                _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeMove)] = updatedMoves;
            } else {
                [_objectChanges removeObjectForKey:@(NSFetchedResultsChangeMove)];
            }
        }

        NSMutableArray *deletes = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
        if ([deletes count] > 0) {
            NSMutableIndexSet *deletedSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
            [deletes filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSIndexPath *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
                return ![deletedSections containsIndex:evaluatedObject.section];
            }]];
        }

        NSMutableArray *inserts = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
        if ([inserts count] > 0) {
            NSMutableIndexSet *insertedSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
            [inserts filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSIndexPath *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
                return ![insertedSections containsIndex:evaluatedObject.section];
            }]];
        }

        UICollectionView *collectionView = [self collectionView];

        [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
            NSIndexSet *deletedSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
            if ([deletedSections count] > 0) {
                [collectionView deleteSections:deletedSections];
            }

            NSIndexSet *insertedSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
            if ([insertedSections count] > 0) {
                [collectionView insertSections:insertedSections];
            }

            NSArray *deletedItems = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
            if ([deletedItems count] > 0) {
                [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:deletedItems];
            }

            NSArray *insertedItems = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
            if ([insertedItems count] > 0) {
                [collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:insertedItems];
            }

            NSArray *reloadItems = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate)];
            if ([reloadItems count] > 0) {
                [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:reloadItems];
            }

            NSArray *moveItems = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeMove)];
            for (NSArray *paths in moveItems) {
                [collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:paths[0] toIndexPath:paths[1]];
            }
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                _objectChanges = nil;
                _sectionChanges = nil;

        }];
}
```

BTW: this also happens when I import new photos which also change the promoted photo.

Comment: Can you add your `numberOfItemsInSection` method implementation? The error is saying you are inserting an item into section 0 (which will then have 2 items from 1 initially), but when the collection view then goes to display that cell, your `numberOfItemsInSection` is still returning 1 for section 0.

Comment: it only has two lines

`id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[[self fetchedResultsController] sections] objectAtIndex:section];
 return [[sectionInfo objects] count];`

Comment: @Mark your are right, that it will have two items after the update, but even that makes somehow no sense, as promoted is only for one item YES. So it's weird that there should be two items in Section 0

Comment: It looks like when you get a new promoted photo, you are inserting a new cell in section 0 instead of refreshing the one cell. You should either refresh the one cell to load the new promoted photo, or delete the original promoted photo cell when you add the new cell so that the number of cells in section 0 will match the count returned by `numberOfItemsInSection`.